# importing numba module shows ImportError

Tags: python, numba

so i am currently using vs code with anaconda, both latest versions. When trying to import jit from numba like so,

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)

@jit(nopython=True) # Set "nopython" mode for best performance, equivalent to @njit
def go_fast(a): # Function is compiled to machine code when called the first time
    trace = 0.0
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):   # Numba likes loops
        trace += np.tanh(a[i, i]) # Numba likes NumPy functions
    return a + trace              # Numba likes NumPy broadcasting

print(go_fast(x))
```

as in the numba site, it gives the error,

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'jit' from partially initialized module 'numba' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

when i try

```
import numba
numba.__version__
```

it shows

```
'0.51.2'
```

i made sure that i am using the anaconda base environment, which is where numba was installed, included with anaconda

why is this issue occuring and how i can i solve this? any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the name of your python script that you are trying to import `numba` from?

Comment: omg it was numba.py. i just changed it to numba_test.py and of course, it worked. thanks, the fact that the name of the file could be an issue never occurred to me.

Comment: would be nice to add the answer and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of your python script and see if that works. :P

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).